# add string literal from resharper

Tags: resharper

In the following example, how would I turn `"UIIconUpBrush"` into a string constant using resharper 7.

```
borderMain.SetResourceReference(Border.BorderBrushProperty, "UIIconUpBrush");
```

This is easy with coderush but I see no easy way in resharper.

Answer (score 2):

- Select the whole of the string (eg by double-clicking, or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (possible repeated))
- Choose `Introduce Field...` (with its direct shortcut (typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), or from the popup Refactor This menu (typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), or from `ReSharper | Refactor`)
- In the `Introduce Field` dialog, select the `Introduce Constant` radio button (and make whatever changes you want to the defaults)
- Choose `Next`

And you're done.

Comment: The only way this would work with whatever settings I have is if I hit ctrl - r then f while the whole word with brackets is highlighted.

Comment: @user1603573 good point, updated to indicate that the string should be selected. I don't think the delimiting quotes need to be in the selection, though.